# How do I dynamically pass a form field value into a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On submit I would like to display the value of an input field with the #firstname id into a div using jQuery.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}proteinlaunch/form/checkaddress',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('form#proteinForm').serialize(),
    success: handleData

  });
  e.preventDefault();

  function handleData(data) {
    //do some stuff



    var text = $('input#firstname').text();
    $("div#mydiv").html(text);
  }

})
```

My form element is:

```
<input class="fname" id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
```

My html is:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Try `$('input#firstname')` **`.val();`** instead of `.text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.val()` instead of `.text();` when you want to get the value of an input field :

```
$("div#mydiv").html( $('input#firstname').val() );
```

**NOTE :** If the value the input isn't supposed to be HTML it will be better to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

```js
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: '{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}proteinlaunch/form/checkaddress',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('form#proteinForm').serialize(),
    success: handleData
  });
});

function handleData(data) {
  var text = $('input#firstname').val();
  $("div#mydiv").html(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input class="fname" id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
</form>

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!